# Should programs remove temporary files in /tmp?

Tags: files, filesystems, c, posix, tmp

I have a program which uses temporary files, created using the `mkstemps` function.  The files are created inside the `/tmp` directory.

Does these files get removed automatically on program exit?

I'm wondering if my program should remove these files before exit.  If they aren't removed automatically, is it acceptable to not remove them, and have them remain in `/tmp`?  Or is it better practice to remove them using `unlink` or `remove` before program exit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files created by one of [the `mkstemp` family of functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html) aren’t automatically deleted on program exit. Depending on their contents, you can choose to leave them in `/tmp`, which is typically cleaned up periodically, but that’s somewhat poor form.

There are two main ways you can handle this cleanly:

- if no other process needs to be able to open the temporary file, or you can deal with this by passing file descriptors, then you can delete the file immediately after `mkstemps` returns — the file will still exist, but it will no longer appear in directory listings, and it will be deleted as soon as you `close` the file descriptor;
- otherwise, register an exit function with `atexit` which deletes the file.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove them immediately after creating them with `open(O_CREAT)` or similar, and only use them via the returned file descriptor.

Higher level interfaces like `tmpfile(3)` will do that for you, and may even use better approaches, like `O_TMPFILE` on Linux (see the [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) manpage for a description).

Removing them "before exit" is broken, because your program may terminate abnormally, before being able to remove them.